# Switching through TextInputs in React-Native

Tags: react-native

What is the proper way to switch to the next `TextInput` in React-Native >0.44.0?

I tried it with refs and `.focus()`, but this didn't work. All answers I found were outdated.

Comment: What error did you get when using focus()

Comment: that it is not defined and not a function

Comment: Did you try assigning the ref like: `<TextInput ref={el => this.refs = el} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify ref to the next textinput.  Try this

```
  <TextInput
    placeholder="first"
    placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    returnKeyType="next"
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.second.focus()}
  />

  <TextInput
    placeholder="second"
    placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    returnKeyType="done"
    ref={input => (this.second = input)}   // This line is important
  />
```

Comment: My problem was, that I had nested Elements and tried to pass `ref` through to the children of my component, but the `ref` attribute is never passed through by React